# I need a javascript timestamp when changing an option in a form.

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need a timestamp to change each time a person changes his/her work area. The time change will be posted in a text box next to their name. How do I tie this user action to get a timestamp in the text box? -Thank you

```
  <h1>Current Assignments</h1>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function filter_seconds(date){
  return date.replace(/(\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2})\:\d{2}/, '$1')
  }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
```

```
<h3>David</h3><input type="text" id="date" value="" />
   <select class="form-control">
      <option>Pictures</option>
      <option>ERO's</option>
      <option>ERO's</option>
      <option>Appraisal</option>
      <option>Wholesale</option>
      <option>Wholesale Pictues</option>
      <option>Lunch Break</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: The answer below is apt, but keep in mind, javascript is entirely client side. Just because it's in a box next to the user's name doesn't mean that it's saved in the server and just because your script puts a date next to the user's name doesn't mean that if you submit the form that it will reflect accurate data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get a timestamp whenever the user changes his/her work area i.e. selects one of the options in your `select` menu. You could do that in javascript by exploiting the `onchange` property like so:

```
 <select class="form-control" onchange="foo()">
  <option>Pictures</option>
  <option>ERO's</option>
  <option>ERO's</option>
  <option>Appraisal</option>
  <option>Wholesale</option>
  <option>Wholesale Pictues</option>
  <option>Lunch Break</option>
 </select>
```

Whenever, an `option` is changed, the function `foo()` is called. The function could look like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function foo(){
     var d = new Date();
     console.log(d.getTime());
     //You could then update the innerHTML of suitable elements with this value.
   }
 </script>
```

You should check out the [Javascript Date reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to understand which date method you would like to use in your case( there are many like `getMonth(),getSeconds()` etc.). Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

**EDIT**

1. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq0nta3a/1/) for a working demo.
2. Adding selected options along with timestamp - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq0nta3a/3/)

Comment: Ok, Thank you! Now it works... but the time stamp is erased each time the page is refreshed and I need it to stay or at least log it with each event <option> change. Here is my updated code, but I'm not sure how to handle the "onchange" log with timestamp. <script>
  function foo(){
     var d = new Date();
     document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d;
     //You could then update the innerHTML of suitable elements with this value.
   }
 </script>
<h3>Amber</h3><br>
<p id="time"></p>
 <select class="form-control" onchange="foo()">
  <option>Task1</option>
 <option>Task2</option></select>

Comment: @DelmasSkipper, I get your point, you just need to use the `.toString()` method to embed the date object in the `HTML` of the element. I have created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq0nta3a/1/) that logs the timestamps into a `p` tag on similar lines of your code. Check that out. Also updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, like that...but how can I log the timestamps + what option they select at that time in a form that isn't erased every time I refresh the page? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @DelmasSkipper, it's really simple. You just pass the selected parameter to the `onchange()` method like so: `onchange(this)`. I have updated the answer to include the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq0nta3a/3/)

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much! When refreshing the page the log is erased. How can I keep it there on the screen even after the user refreshes or goes to another page and returns later? PHP to mySQL or can I store it in the browser somehow?

Comment: @DelmasSkipper, I answered the question as per your description. You should have included it in the original question IMHO. This is actually a separate question in itself and has a lot of answers on SO. However to reiterate, there are two easy options to store data besides storing it in a full-fledged MYSQL database. One is using the [browser storage API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) which is client side. Other could be using [session variabales](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) or cookies in PHP.

Comment: Go through the documentations for both. I'd personally suggest using the HTML web storage because it is really easy to get started with and would work well for small amount of data like in your case. I have deliberately not added the code because it seemed out of scope of the posted question. But it's as simple as doing : `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith"); localStorage.getItem("lastname")`. It should be a simple exercise.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. I didn't realized the output was going to disappear after refresh until after the code was how I wanted it to work. Thanks again for all your help. I will look around SO to see what I can find.

Comment: Here is what I've got so far. It doesn't work for me. Not sure what I've done wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/skippd01/qej9t491/

Comment: @DelmasSkipper, I am sorry but I can not correct your code till you get it right. My idea was to point you in the right direction and the demo that I gave works perfectly fine for me. That said, it didn't work for you for a variety of reasons. First you need to run javascript on "No wrap - in <head>" option. It's in the top left of the screen, where you select frameworks and extensions. Secondly, the functions you defined `save` and `load` need to be tied to an **event**.  Functions are **triggered** on [javascript events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

Comment: You probably wanted to exploit the `onclick()` method of the two buttons that you had created. Also, I pass the parameter `a` to the function `foo()`, it is not available inside `save()` and `load()`.  Again, you need to read about lexical scope of a function. Quite simply, variables passed to one function are 'local' to it and  just can't be accessed inside another function. That's another reading you will have to do on your own as clarifying this concepts in a comments thread is too broad of an exercise and you'll benefit more if you do it yourself.

Comment: Finally, you used the web storage API in your example which is great! Keeping these pointers into mind. I have updated your demo in two versions [1](http://jsfiddle.net/qej9t491/1/) and [2](http://jsfiddle.net/qej9t491/2/). The first version just stores the contents of the paragraph with id `time` into a variable `log` and stores it into the browser. The other version maintains separate variables for all the options. **However**, you have duplicate entries for "ERO's" in your options, I have removed that. And restores them into a separate paragraph tag.

Comment: The values in both the versions **persist** even on browser refresh . I'm not going to be able to help you with each line of code now. I would appreciate if you close this question and mark the answer as accepted, so that others in a similar problem also benefit out of it. As far as the demos I created are concerned, they are pretty simplistic and should solve your problem entirely. Feel free to play around with them. Happy coding :)